# Get image meta in Wordpdess

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the image meta of my thumbnails in WordPress, but it just keeps failing. I have no idea why is that. Reading the documentation I can't really see what I'm doing wrong. See (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_read_image_metadata). How would you do this?

This is my code basically:

```
  $url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url();
  var_dump(wp_read_image_metadata($url));
```

All this does is to return `bool(false)`

Comment: wp_read_image_date needs a image path, not a url. Use get_attached_file(get_post_thumbnail_id()) instead of get_the_post_thumbnail_url()

Comment: But of course. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below and let me know if it works for you.

```
<?php
    $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
    echo $feat_image;

?>
```